# How do I store a Gruppe Sechs van in the airport hangar?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In *GTA V* story mode, I've recently been trying to store a Gruppe Sechs security van. I've noticed that you can't store this van in a regular garage, so I tried the hangar instead. I stole the van but haven't blown open the back doors.

If I leave the van, will it stay in the hangar? Or do I have to blow open the back doors?

Comment: What is the mission objective telling you to do? You shouldn't be needing to store vehicles yourself.

Comment: @pboss3010 There is no mission objective telling me to do that, I just want to store the van.

Comment: Oh, you picked it up in free roam time? Hmm, I've never tried to store one. If it says you can't store it in the paid garage when you drive up to it, then you probably can't store it anywhere.

Comment: @pboss3010 Yeah, I loaded in this session and it wasn't there, so I'm guessing you can't store it.